# Jquery toggle action for animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to link jQuery toggle and animate functions together. When i click on the box, its size should change. My codes js fiddles snip is here. Why doesn't it work? It disappears on startup.

[JS Fiddle snip](http://jsfiddle.net/x7f34vr5/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.adiv').toggle(
   function(){
        $(this).animate({
            width: "150",
            height: "150",
        }, 1000);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).animate({
            width: "77", 
            height: "77",
        }, 1000);        
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toggle will hide/show you element so because your element is visible at initial load the first time your toggle function is called it will animate but then the toggle will set a display none on the element causing it to hide. You should not use the toggle function for this.

You should use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var big = false;
    $('.adiv').on('click', function(){
        if( big ) {
             $(this).animate({
                    width: "77", 
                    height: "77",
                }, 1000);        
        } else {
            $(this).animate({
                    width: "150",
                    height: "150",
                }, 1000); 
        }
        big = !big;
    });
});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/x7f34vr5/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a click handler, or it will just run right away. eg.

```
$('.adiv').click( function () {
// Do stuff here
});
```

Toggle and animate don't really go together - here's a different way of doing it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.adiv').click( function () {
        var newSize = $(this).width() > 77 ? 77 : 150;

        $(this).animate({
            width: newSize,
            height: newSize,
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/98grnsqn/1/).